# ¿Por qué la palabra "ataúd" lleva acento?

Tags: ortografía

Me confunde la ortografía de la palabra "ataúd". Las reglas ortográficas del idioma español (o sea, las reglas que sé) sugieren que no debamos poner un acento en esta palabra. Entonces, ¿por qué lo ponemos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bueno, primero hay que ver la silabificación de esta palabra:

> a - ta - ud

Ya que termina con una *-d*, las reglas de acentación indica que sería posible prescindirse de tilde solo si es palabra aguda.  Ahora nos preguntamos, ¿dónde se acentúa la palabra?

> a - ta - **ud**

Entonces, sería fácil pensar que no debe haber tilde porque es palabra aguda terminada en consonante (excepto *n* o *s*).  Pero si tomamos la palabra *ataud*, y lo partimos según las normas de pronunciación, tenemos otro resultado:

> a - **taud**

¿Por qué pasa eso?  Pues, siempre que tengamos una vocal fuerte (o abierta) con una vocal débil (o cerrada) como tenemos con la *a* (fuerte) y la *u* (débil), se las considera como diptongo.  Y a un diptongo le recae el acento sobre la vocal fuerte, es decir, la *a*.  Pero ya dijimos que debe recaer sobre la *u* y no la *a* que recibe el acento.  Por tanto, tildamos la *u* para indicar que la *u* es fuerte y no débil.  Con dos vocales fuertes hay hiato (/a.u/) en vez de diptongo /aw/), y la tilde indica la sílaba acentuada.

Si la palabra tuviese otra vocal fuerte (por ejemplo *ataod*, *ataad* o *ataed*), no sería necesaria la tilde.  Si tuviese la otra débil (*ataíd*) sería necesaria por las mismas razones.

Answer (score 5):

En esta palabra **no hay diptongo**, hay hiato. Repito, **no hay diptongo**. Hay hiato cuando tenemos dos vocales seguidas, pero pertenecientes a distintas sílabas.

> "Ataúd" tiene 3 sílabas: a - ta - úd

Cuando hay hiato siempre se coloca tilde en la vocal cerrada tónica, aunque con ello no se sigan las reglas generales de acentuación. Ejemplos:

> baúl (ba-úl),
>   sabía (sa-bí-a),
>   búho(bú-ho).

- Vocales cerradas: i, u.
- Vocales abiertas: a, e, o.
- Sílaba tónica: lleva la mayor fuerza de voz.
- Silaba átona: no lleva la mayor fuerza de voz.

Comment: "Repito **no hay diptongo**" suena a regaño. Gracias por tu explicación.