# ¿Por qué la palabra "raíces" lleva acento?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

En la palabra "raíces" la sílaba tónica es la penúltima, haciendo de ella una palabra grave.

Entonces, ¿por qué lleva acento, si las palabras graves se acentúan cuando no terminan en n, s o vocal y esta palabra términa en "s"?

Comment: Es un caso muy parecido a [¿Por qué la palabra “ataúd” lleva acento?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14963/1674): se trata de una tilde para romper un diptongo.

Comment: Como dice @fedorqui y como se ve en la pregunta que enlaza, si no le pusieras tilde se pronunciaría [rái-ces]. Luego para indicar que la pronunciación es diferente a como se espera debes poner la tilde.

Comment: @walen sí, lo es, pero la respuesta aceptada allí no enlaza a la _Ortografía 2010_ y tampoco deja claro que "raíces" lo que tiene es un hiato, así que he intentado dar una respuesta que espero que sea canónica.

Comment: @walen cierto, soy consciente, pero tampoco enlaza a la _Ortografía_ de la RAE. En todo caso, el que yo haya dejado aquí mi respuesta no quita para que se cierre por duplicada si se considera oportuno.

Comment: Sí, probablemente sea un buen momento para actualizar el otro hilo aportando respuestas canónicas (la de guifa lo es bastante) y que así pueda enlazarse en casos como este. ¿A alguien se le ocurre un título lo suficientemente genérico para añadir al que ya tiene la otra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[La pregunta enlazada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14963/1674) por @fedorqui en su comentario debería resolver tu problema. El único problema es que tanto el comentario como la respuesta aceptada en la otra pregunta hablan de "romper el diptongo", sin aclarar que en realidad lo que tenemos en palabras como *raíces* o *ataúd* son [hiatos](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QMQTZaazPlqhayNw):

> Los hiatos son secuencias de dos vocales que se pronuncian en sílabas distintas. En español, constituyen hiatos [...] las siguientes combinaciones vocálicas:
>
> - Una vocal cerrada tónica (/i/, /u/) seguida o precedida de una vocal abierta átona (/a/, /e/, /o/): *po.d*í.a, *r*í.o, *des.v*í.e, *p*ú.a, *pun.t*ú.e, *fl*ú.o*r*, *r*a.í*z*, *r*e.í*r*, *e.g*o.í*s.ta*, *t*a.*h*ú*r*, *f*e.ú.*cho*, *fi.n*o.ú.*grio*.
> - Dos vocales abiertas (/a/, /e/, /o/): *c*a.e*r*, a.ho.*go*, *r*o.e*r*, *t*e.a.*tro*, *bar.ba.c*o.a.
> - Dos vocales iguales: *al.b*a.ha.*ca*, *r*e.e.*le.gir*, *ch*i.i.*ta*, *l*o.o*r*, *d*u.u*n.vi.ra.to*.

Fíjate que la palabra "raíces" entra en el primer caso, de hecho su versión singular aparece como ejemplo de este tipo de hiatos. Comenta también la *Ortografía 2010* de la RAE lo siguiente sobre la [acentuación de los hiatos](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KebkjNkZTXmLzCXP):

> Las palabras que contienen un hiato formado por una vocal cerrada tónica seguida o precedida por una vocal abierta llevan siempre tilde en la vocal cerrada, con independencia de las reglas generales de acentuación. Por eso se acentúan gráficamente palabras como *ser*ía*s*, *sab*ía*is* [...]; lo mismo ocurre en *r*aí*z*, *r*eí*r*, oí*r*, *l*aú*d* o *t*a*h*ú*r*, que llevan asimismo tilde aun siendo agudas terminadas en consonante distinta de *n* o *s*.

En el caso de "raíces", sí, es llana acabada en *s*, pero nótese que dice que estos hiatos llevan tilde **con independencia de las normas generales de acentuación**. De no llevarla, el hiato se pronunciaría como un diptongo: /rái.ces/.